# Speed reduced icon appering on Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

This thing continuously appears when I start working on Jupyter Notebook. Whenever I open any file in it this thing appears after some time. I have no clue what it is.

[image: Speed reduced image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The speed reduced was nothing to with Jupyter. I had a video speed increase decrease extension installed in chrome. I guess there was some sort of bug in the extension.